# SwiftUI equivalent of UITextField.inputAccessoryView

Tags: swiftui, inputaccessoryview

I'm trying to add a button to my TextField's keyboard as we do with UITextField.inputAccessoryView before. But I cannot find a function for it. Am I missing something? Or did Apple miss to add that function?